# Showing message like " Blocked by package.config"

Tags: nuget

In VS Manage Nuget Packages window, When choose nuget from browse and see the listed versions, the message showing like *Blocked by package.config* after under this message all the version again listed. This is for all packages in nuget.org.

Can anyone tell me the reason why shown that message like that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHWPG.png)

Answer (score 0):

packages.config has an optional attribute [`allowedVersions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config#schema), which can be used to [constrain the versions that are allowed to be installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#constraining-upgrade-versions).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug that will be fixed in NuGet 5.4 : https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8679

You still can use the command `Update-Package` to change the version of any installed package.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this steps:

1. Remove the "AllowedVersions" attribute from "packages.config"
2. Try to reinstall the package.
3. the package will be installed successfully.

Comment: Thanks, @dboy can you tell me how to go on the next line

Comment: you could check this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138628/textile-style-for-numbered-and-bullet-lists.